# Issue in creating custom report magento 1.9

Tags: module, reports, magento1.9.2.4

I have problem with report when i was trying to create custom report(I am learning from magento default report module)

Error was

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function hasData() on null in

/var/www/html/balloonshopae/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Grid/Abstract.php:102 Stack trace: #0

/var/www/html/balloonshopae/app/code/local/Company/Advancereport/Block/Adminhtml/Report/Sales/Sales/Grid.php(81): 

Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid_Abstract->addColumn('total_qty_invoi...', Array) #1 

/var/www/html/balloonshopae/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(624): Company_Advancereport_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Sales_Sales_Grid->_prepareColumns() #2 

/var/www/html/balloonshopae/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid() #3 

/var/www/html/balloonshopae/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(922): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml() #4 

/var/www/html/balloonshopae/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml() #5 

/var/www/html/balloonshopae/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getCh in 

/var/www/html/balloonshopae/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Grid/Abstract.php on line 102
```

Here is my controller action (controllers/Adminhtml/AdvancereportController.php)

```
public function salesAction()
{
    $this->_title($this->__('Reports'))->_title($this->__('Sales'))->_title($this->__('Sales'));

    $this->_showLastExecutionTime(Mage_Reports_Model_Flag::REPORT_ORDER_FLAG_CODE, 'sales');

    $this->_initAction()
        ->_setActiveMenu('report/sales/sales')
        ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Sales Report'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Sales Report'));

    $gridBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('report_sales_sales.grid');
    $filterFormBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('grid.filter.form');

    $this->_initReportAction(array(
        $gridBlock,
        $filterFormBlock
    ));

    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Here is my layout xml file (app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/advancereport.xml)

```
<advancereport_adminhtml_advancereport_sales>
    <update handle="report_sales"/>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="advancereport/adminhtml_report_sales_sales" template="report/grid/container.phtml" name="sales.report.grid.container">
            <block type="adminhtml/store_switcher" template="report/store/switcher/enhanced.phtml" name="store.switcher">
                <action method="setStoreVarName"><var_name>store_ids</var_name></action>
            </block>
            <block type="sales/adminhtml_report_filter_form_order" name="grid.filter.form">
                <action method="addReportTypeOption" translate="value">
                    <key>created_at_order</key>
                    <value>Order Created Date</value>
                </action>
                <action method="addReportTypeOption" translate="value">
                    <key>updated_at_order</key>
                    <value>Order Updated Date</value>
                </action>
                <action method="setFieldOption" translate="value">
                    <field>report_type</field>
                    <option>note</option>
                    <value>Order Updated Date report is real-time, does not need statistics refreshing.</value>
                </action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</advancereport_adminhtml_advancereport_sales>
```

here is my block file (Block/Adminhtml/Report/Sales/Sales.php)

```
class Company_Advancereport_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Sales_Sales extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'advancereport';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_report_sales_sales';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('reports')->__('Total Ordered Report');
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('report/grid/container.phtml');
        $this->_removeButton('add');
        $this->addButton('filter_form_submit', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Show Report'),
            'onclick'   => 'filterFormSubmit()'
        ));
    }

    public function getFilterUrl()
    {
        $this->getRequest()->setParam('filter', null);
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/sales', array('_current' => true));
    }
}
```

Here is grid file (Advancereport/Block/Adminhtml/Report/Sales/Sales/Grid.php)

```
class Company_Advancereport_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Sales_Sales_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid_Abstract
{
    protected $_columnGroupBy = 'period';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setCountTotals(true);
    }

    public function getResourceCollectionName()
    {
        return ($this->getFilterData()->getData('report_type') == 'updated_at_order')
            ? 'sales/report_order_updatedat_collection'
            : 'sales/report_order_collection';
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('period', array(
            'header'        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Period'),
            'index'         => 'period',
            'width'         => 100,
            'sortable'      => false,
            'period_type'   => $this->getPeriodType(),
            'renderer'      => 'adminhtml/report_sales_grid_column_renderer_date',
            'totals_label'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total'),
            'html_decorators' => array('nobr'),
        ));

        $this->addColumn('orders_count', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Orders'),
            'index'     => 'orders_count',
            'type'      => 'number',
            'total'     => 'sum',
            'sortable'  => false
        ));

        $this->addColumn('total_qty_ordered', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Sales Items'),
            'index'     => 'total_qty_ordered',
            'type'      => 'number',
            'total'     => 'sum',
            'sortable'  => false
        ));

        $this->addColumn('total_qty_invoiced', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Items'),
            'index'     => 'total_qty_invoiced',
            'type'      => 'number',
            'total'     => 'sum',
            'sortable'  => false,
            'visibility_filter' => array('show_actual_columns')
        ));

        if ($this->getFilterData()->getStoreIds()) {
            $this->setStoreIds(explode(',', $this->getFilterData()->getStoreIds()));
        }
        $currencyCode = $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
        $rate = $this->getRate($currencyCode);

        $this->addColumn('total_income_amount', array(
            'header'        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Sales Total'),
            'type'          => 'currency',
            'currency_code' => $currencyCode,
            'index'         => 'total_income_amount',
            'total'         => 'sum',
            'sortable'      => false,
            'rate'          => $rate,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('total_revenue_amount', array(
            'header'            => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Revenue'),
            'type'              => 'currency',
            'currency_code'     => $currencyCode,
            'index'             => 'total_revenue_amount',
            'total'             => 'sum',
            'sortable'          => false,
            'visibility_filter' => array('show_actual_columns'),
            'rate'              => $rate,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('total_profit_amount', array(
            'header'            => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Profit'),
            'type'              => 'currency',
            'currency_code'     => $currencyCode,
            'index'             => 'total_profit_amount',
            'total'             => 'sum',
            'sortable'          => false,
            'visibility_filter' => array('show_actual_columns'),
            'rate'              => $rate,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('total_invoiced_amount', array(
            'header'        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoiced'),
            'type'          => 'currency',
            'currency_code' => $currencyCode,
            'index'         => 'total_invoiced_amount',
            'total'         => 'sum',
            'sortable'      => false,
            'rate'          => $rate,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('total_paid_amount', array(
            'header'            => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Paid'),
            'type'              => 'currency',
            'currency_code'     => $currencyCode,
            'index'             => 'total_paid_amount',
            'total'             => 'sum',
            'sortable'          => false,
            'visibility_filter' => array('show_actual_columns'),
            'rate'              => $rate,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('total_refunded_amount', array(
            'header'        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Refunded'),
            'type'          => 'currency',
            'currency_code' => $currencyCode,
            'index'         => 'total_refunded_amount',
            'total'         => 'sum',
            'sortable'      => false,
            'rate'          => $rate,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('total_tax_amount', array(
            'header'        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Sales Tax'),
            'type'          => 'currency',
            'currency_code' => $currencyCode,
            'index'         => 'total_tax_amount',
            'total'         => 'sum',
            'sortable'      => false,
            'rate'          => $rate,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('total_tax_amount_actual', array(
            'header'            => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tax'),
            'type'              => 'currency',
            'currency_code'     => $currencyCode,
            'index'             => 'total_tax_amount_actual',
            'total'             => 'sum',
            'sortable'          => false,
            'visibility_filter' => array('show_actual_columns'),
            'rate'              => $rate,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('total_shipping_amount', array(
            'header'        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Sales Shipping'),
            'type'          => 'currency',
            'currency_code' => $currencyCode,
            'index'         => 'total_shipping_amount',
            'total'         => 'sum',
            'sortable'      => false,
            'rate'          => $rate,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('total_shipping_amount_actual', array(
            'header'            => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping'),
            'type'              => 'currency',
            'currency_code'     => $currencyCode,
            'index'             => 'total_shipping_amount_actual',
            'total'             => 'sum',
            'sortable'          => false,
            'visibility_filter' => array('show_actual_columns'),
            'rate'              => $rate,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('total_discount_amount', array(
            'header'        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Sales Discount'),
            'type'          => 'currency',
            'currency_code' => $currencyCode,
            'index'         => 'total_discount_amount',
            'total'         => 'sum',
            'sortable'      => false,
            'rate'          => $rate,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('total_discount_amount_actual', array(
            'header'            => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Discount'),
            'type'              => 'currency',
            'currency_code'     => $currencyCode,
            'index'             => 'total_discount_amount_actual',
            'total'             => 'sum',
            'sortable'          => false,
            'visibility_filter' => array('show_actual_columns'),
            'rate'              => $rate,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('total_canceled_amount', array(
            'header'        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Canceled'),
            'type'          => 'currency',
            'currency_code' => $currencyCode,
            'index'         => 'total_canceled_amount',
            'total'         => 'sum',
            'sortable'      => false,
            'rate'          => $rate,
        ));


        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportSalesCsv', Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportSalesExcel', Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Excel XML'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate what problem are you facing?

Comment: update error log

Answer (score 0):

Insufficient data:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function hasData() on null in

this error is in complete please provide full error log as it is

you can find your full log at 

sudo tail -f /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log

your full error is looks like as below:

Uncaught Error: Class 'Classname' not found in /[file_path]/[filename.php]:[line number]